# Azure Function StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException on StringGetAsync

Tags: azure, redis, azure-functions, stackexchange.redis

I am running an azure function app on azure cloud , **from time to time** I am getting the fallowing error:

Exception while executing function: ****Timeout performing SETEX (10000ms), next: GET *****, inst: 140, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 2939, serverEndpoint: *****:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: 4ad57eb720e9(SE.Redis-v2.6.66.47313), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=6,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=69,Free=32698,Min=6,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=69,QueuedItems=54,CompletedItems=8674751), v: 2.6.66.47313 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

It doesn't look like there a specific reason for this to happen.
Any ideas why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

The bottle neck could either be network bandwidth or CPU cycles. Based on the log you shared, you have 69 work threads, so I would first check the CPU usage to be sure you aren't maxing it out.

You are likely not hitting network bandwidth issues assuming you are running on Azure and since the `qs`/`qu` values are 0 but there could be network glitches that are causing the timeouts too but should be transient and resolve on their own.